# Giving different types of variables as input to ML models

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, boosting, multimodality

I have a dataset containing two types of variables. These are - numerical and sequential variables( example is shown below). How can I give both of these variables simultaneously as input to machine learning models like, Xgboost.

Sample Data-

V1
     V2
     Target




1
     [1,2,3]
     1




5
     [2,3,4]
     1



15
   [6,8,9]
     0

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you code `V2` as three separate variables so the model sees all points in the sequence?

Comment: Sure, I will try that, but I was looking for some other ways to deal with this type of variable also.